# Blackjack Javascript problem dealer has 3 cards only needs to have 2

Tags: javascript

This is my first post. I'm new to coding and one of my projects is to create a simple version of Blackjack using Javascript. I made a basic website for it [here](https://heroic-klepon-d347ef.netlify.app/) and I've encountered a problem. The dealer occasionally gets dealt 3 or more cards. The dealer should always have 2 cards. (unless you hit or stay.) Adding cards to the dealer like the player isn't required so I did not write code for it. I have the dealer sum limit set to 13 (I've tried lower/higher numbers, but that doesn't really "fix" the issue.") and also edited the for loops. I thought it could be an array problem. Perhaps I have the arrays too simplified and need to rename the cards?

Here is my code any help or tips would be appreciated!

```js
var dealerSum = 0;
var yourSum = 0;


var dealerAceCount = 0;
var yourAceCount = 0;

var hidden;
var deck;

var canHit = true;

window.onload = function () {
    buildDeck()
    shuffleDeck()
    startGame()
}

function buildDeck() {
    let values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
    let types = ["C", "D", "H", "S"]
    deck = []

    for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            deck.push(values[j] + "-" + types[i]);
        }
    }
    // console.log(deck);
}


function shuffleDeck() {
    for (let i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
        let temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = temp;
    }
    // console.log(deck);
}

function startGame() {
    hidden = deck.pop();
    dealerSum += getValue(hidden);
    dealerAceCount += checkAce(hidden);
    // console.log(hidden);
    // console.log(dealerSum);

    while (dealerSum < 13) {
        let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
        let card = deck.pop();

        cardImg.src = "./cards/" + card + ".png";
        dealerSum += getValue(card);
        dealerAceCount += checkAce(card);
        document.getElementById("dealer-cards").append(cardImg);
    }
    console.log(dealerSum)

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
        let card = deck.pop();
        cardImg.src = "./cards/" + card + ".png";
        yourSum += getValue(card);
        yourAceCount += checkAce(card);
        document.getElementById("your-cards").append(cardImg);


    }
    console.log(yourSum);
    document.getElementById("refresh").addEventListener("click", refresh);
    document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click", hit);
    document.getElementById("stay").addEventListener("click", stay);
}

function hit() {
    if (!canHit) {
        return;
    }
    let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
    let card = deck.pop();
    cardImg.src = "./cards/" + card + ".png";
    yourSum += getValue(card);
    yourAceCount += checkAce(card);
    document.getElementById("your-cards").append(cardImg);

    if (reduceAce(yourSum, yourAceCount) > 21) {
        canHit = false;
    }

}


function stay() {
    dealerSum = reduceAce(dealerSum, dealerAceCount);
    yourSum = reduceAce(yourSum, yourAceCount);

    canHit = false;
    document.getElementById("hidden").src = "./cards/" + hidden + ".png";

    let message = "";
    if (yourSum > 21) {
        message = "You lose! Better luck next time. Refresh to try again!"
    }
    else if (dealerSum > 21) {
        message = "You win! Refresh to play again!"
    }
    else if (yourSum == dealerSum) {
        message = "Tie! Refresh to play again!";
    }
    else if (yourSum > dealerSum) {
        message = "You win! Refresh to play again!";
    }
    else if (yourSum < dealerSum) {
        message = "You lose! Better luck next time. Refresh to play again!";
    }

    document.getElementById("dealer-sum").innerText = dealerSum;
    document.getElementById("your-sum").innerText = yourSum;
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = message;
}

function refresh() {
    window.location.reload();
}


function getValue(card) {
    let data = card.split("-");
    let value = data[0];

    if (isNaN(value)) {
        if (value == "A") {
            return 11;
        }
        return 10;
    }

    return parseInt(value);

}

function checkAce(card) {
    if (card[0] == "A") {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function reduceAce(playerSum, playerAceCount) {
    while (playerSum > 21 && playerAceCount > 0) {
        playerSum -= 10;
        playerAceCount -= 1;
    }
    return playerSum;
}
```

Comment: It's a little more code in the question than is needed, but it looks like the pertinent section is in `startGame()` in the loop where `while (dealerSum < 13) {`?  If that's right, then the fix to the narrow part of the question is a counter, initialized to zero before the loop, and a new loop condition `while (dealerSum < 13 && dealt++ < 2) {`.  More broadly, I can see a few opportunities for code improvement, but we'd need to focus questions around these, or use https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When adding the `&& dealt++ < 2`  the cards disappear. Adding the counter you are talking about I assume would make the new loop work? Would it be adding a counter to the `startGame()` section or editing the loop in the above section(s) to include it?

Comment: Maybe I need to understand the code better. Does startGame run once at the start?  Is that loop for the dealer the way the dealer gets cards?  If so, it should iterate twice, and not check the dealer's total, I think.

Comment: startGame runs once at start. You are correct it is where the dealer gets the cards/card sum from. I think I figured it out with your help actually though! Dealer has 2 cards now. I used the `while (dealerSum < 13 && dealerCount < 1) {` and above it added `let dealerCount = 0`. Thank you so much for the help/advice!